# How do we add a looping music for webpage in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add background music to my game but it's not working out I want it to keep looping even if I move to the second page how can I fix it?

here is what i tried so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <canvas id="bg"></canvas>

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Homepage.js"></script>
     <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6nzGfMla-k&feature=youtu.be" autostart="true" loop="true"
       width="2" height="0"></embed>
</head>
```

Comment: Making the music keep playing even when you move to another page is a lot harder than making it play at all. Stack Overflow is more suited for asking only one question at a time, so I suggest just trying to get the music to play for now. After that, you can look up more about how to do the other thing (using [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and so on) and then create another question if that you can’t get it to work.

Comment: Some browsers block audio from a page until the user has interacted with it. So even if you get audio to play, you have to consider how to make it work with that restriction.

Comment: You could use a frameset as in the 90s running a frame playing music and load the visible content into the other part.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that download that youtube's video audio from [Here](https://mp3juice.cc) just enter video link and download the audio and save it and give it in `<source>`, `src` attribute.
Create audio like this and add `autoplay` and set `loop` to `true`.

```
   <audio autoplay loop="true">
      <source src="yourSong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

Comment: <audio autoplay loop="true">
        <source src="Soundtracks/soundtrack-1-.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>

Comment: download it as an mp3 audio beacuse mp4 is an video format nor the audio one.That's why audio source is not supporting it.

Comment: should it be under a head tag or body tag? coz i changed it to mp3 it still not running

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but keep in mind that this could be a copyright infringement, whereas using a YouTube video is the uploaders liability.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed a YouTube video using the `<embed>` tag. You could use the [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead. Set the `autoplay` and `loop` properties of the `playerVars` object to `1` and the `playlist` property to the same ID as `videoId`.

However, browsers use different strategies to decide whether a web page is allowed to autostart media or not. A certain amount of user interaction has to have taken place already in order to allow it. What you can do is start the music the first time the user interacts by clicking an element on the page. That could be a button that starts the game, a select list the user selects game options from, etc. For this demonstration, I bound to the click event of the whole document.

As the YouTube JS API doesn't seem to work inside Stack snippets, [please see this codepen](https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/gOOoGgW).

***Note:*** Chrome seems to have some issues with this code running in codepen as well. But putting it into a file and uploading it to a server and running it from there, I was able to get it working consistently. The first time via a click anywhere on the document, and on the following page loads via autoplay.

```js
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('playerWrapper', {
    height: '0',
    width: '0',
    videoId: '-6nzGfMla-k',

    playerVars: {
      'autoplay': 1,
      'controls': 0,
      'autohide': 1,
      'enablejsapi': 1,
      'loop': 1,
      'disablekb': 1,
      'fs': 0,
      'modestbranding': 0,
      'showinfo': 0,
      'color': 'white',
      'theme': 'light',
      'rel': 0,
      'playlist': '-6nzGfMla-k'
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': function onPlayerReady(ev) {
        ev.target.playVideo();
      }
    }
  });
}

function startBgMusic() {
  player.playVideo()
  document.removeEventListener('click', startBgMusic);
}

document.addEventListener('click', startBgMusic);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div id="playerWrapper"></div>
This will not work in the Stack snippet preview, please see the linked code pen above!
```

Comment: Because of youtube not allow autoplay in IFrames.

Comment: It should as soon as you click anywhere inside the preview frame. It works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @novruzrhmv that's simply not true. The API explicitly offers the `autoplay` property and a notice on browser restrictions regarding it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Autoplay_and_scripted_playback

Comment: <audio autoplay loop="true">
        <source src="Soundtracks/soundtrack-1-.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>

Comment: I clicked everywhere and it didn't work maybe a problem in my browser ?

Comment: Those autoplay restrictions apply to `audio` and `video` elements as well. You'll also need to trigger playback on user interaction with this approach.

Comment: Chrome seems to have some issues with this code running in codepen as well. But putting it into a file and uploading it to a server and running it from there, I was able to get it working consistently. The first time via a click anywhere on the document, and on the following page loads via autoplay.

Comment: I see that you have unaccepted the answer. Did you still not get it to work? What browser are you using?